# Underscore pluck not working on array of models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
var currentVideos = this.get('items').pluck('video');

//  TODO: Why does pluck not work here?
var currentVideosDurations = _.map(currentVideos, function (currentVideo) {
    return currentVideo.get('duration');
});

var test = _.pluck(currentVideos, 'duration');
console.log("Test:", test);
```

I was wondering why my second pluck doesn't work, but my map works fine? I thought these were equivilant usages.

Here's a screenshot of a console log showing this.get('items') and the array of currentVideos.

[image]

Comment: Can you also post a list of sample collection for this problem

Comment: Yeah one moment. I've uploaded a screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The backbone model object doesn't store the properties you `get` from the model at the top level javascript object. The `currentVideo` backbone model object actually stores the attributes deeper within the javascript object, in (`currentVideo.attributes`).

`_.pluck(currentVideos, 'duration')` checks for the top level attribute (e.g. `currentVideo['duration']`), which doesn't exist.

The distinction is that Backbone Model objects are more sophisticated than basic javascript objects and don't `get` attributes by just retrieving `object['attrName']`.

Comment: @Sushanth-- `currentVideos` is just an array of models, not a collection. `pluck` always returns an array, never a collection. This answer is correct.

Comment: @PeterLyons.. right my bad.. I overlooked a minor point. If pluck would have returned a collection `_.map(currentVideos,`  would have been `_.map(currentVideos.models,` . Thanks for clarifying that

Answer (score 3):

> I thought these were equivilant usages.

Nope. [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) is accessing properties with that name, but `get` is a method invocation. However, to shorten the `map` you can use [`invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke):

```
var currentVideosDurations = _.invoke(currentVideos, "get", "duration");
```